# Why does it always show "Process returned 18 (0*12)" if I don't use "return 0"?

Tags: c, return-value, return-type

I was just trying to see what happen if I don't use "return o". So every time I didn't use "return 0" at the end of the program, it was showing "Process returned 18 (0*12)" if I don't use "return 0".

Why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post a minimal complete program that demonstrates this behavior, and details about how you're running it? (That will make the question more useful for other readers.)

Comment: Looking for it, that was a month ago, just remembered.

Comment: As you know, `main()` is supposed to return a value, 0 for success.  If you don't explicitly return a value, you'll get the effect of a random, garbage return value, based on whatever value happened to be in the register or memory location that your system uses for return values.  But, depending on circumstances, it's common for that "random, garbage" value to always be the same.  In your case, it looks like it was 18.  (I don't know what "*0*12)" means.)

Comment: `0*12` is probably a typo for `0x12` (which is 18).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you omit the `return` statement from a non-void function, you're invoking Undefined Behavior. *Anything* can happen.

Comment: Yes, it should, but it was specifically showing "Process returned 18 (0*12)"..

Comment: and if I use/input the test case number, the return type is showing the test case number(when it's omitted).

Comment: @Felix: It is not very productive to try to figure out what exactly happens when you go into undefined territory. Whatever answer you find (in this case most likely some other data that happened to be in a register or on the stack and ends up being used as the return value) will be highly sensitive to all kinds of factors and nothing to rely on.